# How to calculate specific heat capacity of film and electrolytic capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, thermal, model, esr

I am trying to build a thermal equivalent model of a capacitor and its ESR in Simulink. I know the heat flow rate going into the capacitor, as well as the thermal resistance value, but I am missing the value of Specific Heat Capacity.

I was told by my supervisor that I will need to make an approximation, any idea of what this could be?

Comment: You want the heat capacity, not the specific heat capacity. I think they are mostly aluminum by mass. The specific heat capacity of aluminum is around 900 J/K per kg. So if you multiply 900 * the mass in kg that should get you close to the specific heat of the entire capacitor. Copper is about 400 J/K per kg. If you are able to weigh the leads separately you can use that. Or ask a physics or chemistry professor to help you measure it using calorimetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establish the primary components that make up the mass of the capacitor (for example, polyester resin in a Mylar film cap) and look up the heat capacity for each, then calculate the weighted average based on how much of each you think is in there. Probably one or two materials dominate.

Electrolytic caps will be electrolyte (similar to water), paper (probably negligible), and aluminum mostly (the rubber bung, leads, and shrink insulation probably are negligible)

Comment: That is excellent, thank you so much!